# Bemit : Extending the convention

Tags: html, css, sass, naming-conventions

**Hello everyone,**

I have a question about the **Bemit convention**, just to be sure how you use it and see a possible convergence for all devs :

If you have, for example :

- "div" object, with a class "o-item"
- with inside 2 elements
- "o-item__title"
- "o-item__text"

and imagine you want an item inside the title called "icon", let's see if you agree with me :

```
<div class="o-item">
    <h1 class="o-item__title">
       <span>Some text here for title</span>
       <i class="o-item__title__icon"></i>
    </h1>
    <p class="o-item__text">Text of item</p>
</div>
```

Are you shock by the element with the classname : " class='o-item__title__icon' " ?

I know that all of us call him " class:'o-item__icon' ", but sometimes we can need the convention above.

(Explanation of the proposition : o-item__title__icon = Title is a part of Item Object, and Icon is a part of Title of Item Object)

Tell me your opinion, please !

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BEM quick start guide](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#nesting-1) says:

> An element is always part of a block, not another element. This means
> that element names can't define a hierarchy such as
> block__elem1__elem2.

In case you need an icon to be part of the title - just add one more Block (called **.o-title**) to your code, Icon will be an Element of the Block **.o-title**.

```
<div class="o-item">
    <h1 class="o-item__title o-title">
       <span>Some text here for title</span>
       <i class="o-title__icon"></i>
    </h1>
    <p class="o-item__text">Text of item</p>
</div>
```

This is called [mixes in BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes), you can check how it works on the BEM site, but in few words, it means that you can have global styling (font-size, colors, etc.) for **.o-title** and its icon, that will be used everywhere on your site AND you can have the **.o-item__title** class to be used for title positioning in **.o-item** Block.

Comment: Thanks @Vladislav Akhmetvaliyev, your answer is correct ! It's more efficient to produce code that is reusable than code thats it's not. In the BEM documentation I found also an alternative to the actual way that devs implement BEM convention ! See the link : [link](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#nesting-1). I need sometimes to use the " **search-form__content-button** " (convention) in my coding workday !